# SQL check if array if members contains in table

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `Team_Channels` (Team_Channel_Id, Channel_Id, IsActive, Team_Channel_Name, status, lastmessage)
- `Tc_User` (Tc_User_Id, Team_Channel_Id, User_Id, last_message_read)

`Team_Channel_Id` is a foreign key of `Team_Channels` to `Tc_Users` table.

```
const verifyPrivateChatAlreadyExistsModel = async(req,membersArray) => {
  const request = new sql.Request()

  var membersArray = membersArray;

  var ids = []

    var schannels = await request.query(`SELECT  t1.Team_Channel_Id as schannel_id FROM TC_Users t1 ,TC_Users t2  INNER JOIN Team_Channels TC  ON t2.Team_Channel_Id = TC.Team_Channel_Id   WHERE  t1.Team_Channel_Id  = t2.Team_Channel_Id AND t1.User_Id = ${membersArray[0]} AND  t2.User_Id = ${membersArray[1]} AND TC.Team_Channel_Name = 'private' `)
  }
return schannels.recordset

}
```

**Problem**

`MemberArray` is the array of `User_Id`. I want to check if members in the array have same team channel or not if yes I don't have to create the new channel. The function above gives me if `Team_Channel` exists between two users but if array length is more than two how should I do?

```
 var verifyAlreadyExists = await chatModel.verifyPrivateChatAlreadyExistsModel(req,membersArray)
        if(verifyAlreadyExists.length>0){
            res.status(200).json({
                status:true,
                message:'already exists',
                schannel_id:verifyAlreadyExists[0].schannel_id
            }) 
        }
```

This is how I check if channel already exists.

Comment: Aside... comma joins went out of style when SQL-92 was released over 30 years ago. Why would you mix them with modern `JOIN` clauses?

Comment: To check if a channel exists among all members in the membersArray, you can modify your SQL query using a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the COUNT function

Comment: What happens if the existing group has the same team members plus other members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided `Team_Channel_Id, User_Id` is unique in `Tc_User` and array consists of all differrent member ids you can build a query that counts members by channel kind of

```
with members as (
   select *
   from (
      values
      ( ${membersArray[0]}),
      ..
      ( ${membersArray[<N>-1]})
   ) t(uid)
)
select top(1) Team_Channel_Id 
from members m
join Tc_User tc on m.uid = tc.User_Id
group by Team_Channel_Id
having count(*) = (select count(m2.*) from members m2);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.This is working fine but it is returning more than one team_channel_id if i remove top(1).I want the Team_channel_id only if team_channel contains array containing ids not other users.

Comment: @pankaj using a right join you can count both all members of a channel and array members only, `count(m.ud)`  and take only matching channels.

Comment: That has an injection risk. Consider using a Table Valued Parameter

Comment: @Charlieface Looks like OP's input is array of integers controlled by the apllication rather than end user's input. Otherwise I agree, TVP is a way to go.